# gulp-watch overfolding

Tags: gulp, watch

Im trying to make a simple watch task with this gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('./public/app/styles/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(watch('./public/app/styles/scss/*.scss'))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/app/styles/css'));
});
```

The watch is essentialy working, but it is creating a chain of folders inside my destination that goes like this 'public/app/styles/scss/' and put the css inside it.

Before running the task

```
.
├── Gulpfile.js
└── public
    └── app
        └── styles
            ├── scss
            |   └── some.scss
            └── css
```

After running the task

```
.
├── Gulpfile.js
└── public
    └── app
        └── styles
            ├── scss
            |   └── some.scss
            └── css
                └── public
                    └── app
                        └── styles
                            └── scss
                                └── some.css
```

This should be a simple thing that Im missing, why isn't creating the css inside '.public/app/styles/css'?

Comment: https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch#optionsbase

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just remove the ' ./ ' before each path and it works properly. My bad. Final gruntfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('public/app/styles/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(watch('public/app/styles/scss/*.scss'))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app/styles/css'));
});
```